# Classes in C++: Unable to integrate two old functions into a "class-format"

Tags: c++, function, class, object

*Updated*: I have an assignment where I'm supposed to print out a letter distribution of letters depending on what is typed on the keyboard. The printing should be for an example A:5 B:8 C:0 ... and so on which is done by the functions berakna_histogram_abs and skriv_histogram_abs. The total amount of letters should also be printed out from the first mentioned function. As it seems now it works where the amount for each letter is correct, however not the total amount which is **always 0**.

**My first question is:** Where in the code can I find the problem where the total amount of letters always is 0?

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

// Global constants:
const int ANTAL_BOKSTAVER = 26;  //A-Z
const int ANTAL_SPRAK = 4;
const double TOLK_HJALP[ANTAL_SPRAK][ANTAL_BOKSTAVER]=
       {{8.27,1.48,2.94,4.03,11.78,2.22,1.72,6.77, //English
         7.39,0.12,0.81,3.76,2.85,6.71,7.79,1.54,
         0.05,5.95,6.69,9.07,2.66,1.13,2.14,0.19,
         1.89,0.03},
        {7.97,1.40,3.55,3.79,16.89,1.02,1.00,0.75, //French
         7.08,0.38,0.04,5.51,2.82,8.11,5.19,2.78,
         1.01,6.69,8.35,7.22,6.09,1.35,0.02,0.54,
         0.30,0.15},
        {9.50,1.11,1.53,5.30,8.94,1.74,3.57,3.94,  //Swedish
         3.98,0.89,3.26,4.93,3.41,8.46,5.01,1.77,
         0.00,6.73,5.56,9.20,1.94,2.42,0.00,0.05,
         0.45,0.00},
        {5.12,1.95,3.57,5.07,16.87,1.35,3.00,5.79, //German
         8.63,0.19,1.14,3.68,3.12,10.64,1.74,0.42,
         0.01,6.30,6.99,5.19,3.92,0.77,1.79,0.01,
         0.69,1.24}};


// Class declaration
class Text
{
private:
    string text;
     bool histOK;
     int f[ANTAL_BOKSTAVER];
public:
Text ();
Text (string nytext, bool nyhistOK,int nyf[] );
 string get_text();
 bool get_histOK();
 int get_f();
 void setText(string nyText);
 bool beraknaHistogramAbs(const string &str,int hist[]);
 void skrivHistogramAbs(string Alfab, int hist[]);
    
};

//Funktiondeklarations
bool beraknaHistogramAbs(const string &str,int hist[]);
void skriv_histogram_abs(string Alfab, int hist[]);

// Main program:
int main()
{
string text, alfabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
bool histOK = true;
int f[ANTAL_BOKSTAVER];

Text minText; // skapar ett objekt
  
cout <<"Ge en rad med text:" << endl;
getline(cin,text);
 
cout << "\nResultat för bokstäverna A-Z" << endl;
cout << "Totala antalet bokstäver: " << true << endl;
    


  // Calling constructor
  minText.setText( text );
 histOK = minText.beraknaHistogramAbs(text,f);
  minText.skrivHistogramAbs(alfabet,f );

  return 0;
}
//Class implementation

Text::Text()
{
    text="";
    histOK=true;
    
}

Text::Text (string nytext, bool nyhistOK,int nyf[])
{
    text=nytext;
    histOK=nyhistOK;
        }

string Text::get_text()
{
    return text;
}

bool Text::get_histOK()
{
    return histOK;
}



bool Text::beraknaHistogramAbs(const string &str,int hist[])
{
    int index, totA=0;
    char b;
    for (int i=0; i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; i++) {
    hist[i] = 0;
      }
     
     for (int i = 0; i <(int)str.length();i++)
     {
         b = toupper(str.at(i));
         index = b - 'A';
          
         if (isalpha(b))
         { hist[index] +=1;
              totA+=1;
         }
     }
    
    return totA;
}
    bool letters (int &totA) // A bool variable is returned that is true if there contains any letters, else false.
    {
        bool status=true;
        if(totA==0){
        status=false;
      }
        return true;
}

void Text::skrivHistogramAbs(string Alfab, int hist[])
{  int i = 0;
  
    cout << "\nLetter Distribution: " << endl;
    cout << "Letters" << "\t" << "Amount" << endl;

    
    while (i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER)
     {
       cout << Alfab[i] << ":\t" << hist[i] << endl; i++;
     }
}

void Text::setText(string nyText)
{
    text=nyText;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of having a class.  Use `std::map`, `std::getline` and `std::string` in the `main()` function.

Comment: Or instead of `std::map`, you could use an array of 256 slots.  Use the character as an index into the array:  `int counts[256] = {0}; /*...*/ counts[text[i]]++;`

Comment: It’s an assignment so I have to use classes

Comment: I have updated the code if this makes more sense to you!